# how to check if a php file run via scheuled task is working

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a php script running from a batch file. What is the best way to test if this is working.

Currently the BAT file has this:

c:\php\php.exe -f c:\www\somedomain\customcode\automated_scripts\simple_email.php

I tried double clicking the batch file to see if it will run the php script but the code inside did not seem to be doing anything.

To code samples used in that file:

```
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
```

and

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: myemail@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: anotheremaik@someoneelse.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();            

    mail('anotheremaik@someoneelse.com',"hello test","testing msg",$headers);
```

The email did not get sent and a file was not created on the server...is there a better way to test or output some debug data?

Comment: I think your options are really only emails or to log information to a text file. I will be interested to see what other people suggest for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run the script from command line without using the batch file to make sure it's even working correctly.

If the script runs from command line but not from batch, then there may be a problem with your batch file setup. It looks fine to me but there may be something specific to your setup, OS, and/or permissions which isn't clear here.

When running it as a scheduled task you may be able to use exit codes to determine if the script completes successfully. I personally have never tried this with PHP and windows, but you may be able to use exit(0); for a successful execution, and exit(1); for a failed execution. That result may show up in the exit code column of scheduled tasks (again, I'm not sure about this).

Generally speaking, it's best to log output to a file for debugging purposes since you can get contextual information about the problem (not just a success/fail status). You can use PHP's error_log() method to write to the existing log file. You may need to edit your php.ini file to set log_errors = On and error_log = syslog. On Windows I believe this will cause PHP to log to the event log.

Comment: Thanks, ran it through cmd line and it was a pathing issue. Didn't realise that it would output errors direct to cmd but it does which works fine for me.